# Aligning XAML ToolBarPanels

Tags: xaml, toolbar

I have to create a control which aligns some of its button on the left and some others on the right in one row.
I've immediatly thinked to WPF Toolbar so I've typed:

```
...
<ToolBarTray DockPanel.Dock="Top">
    <ToolBar ToolBarTray.Locked="True" Width="{Binding ElementName=Tray, Path=ActualWidth}">
    <DockPanel>
        <ToolBarPanel DockPanel.Dock="Left">
            <Button ...>
        </ToolBarPanel>
        <ToolBarPanel DockPanel.Dock="Right">
            <Button ...>
        </ToolBarPanel>
    </DockPanel>
    </ToolBar>
</ToolBarTray>
...
```

but this didn't work: the buttons with dockpanel.dock = right are just attached on the right of the first ToolBarPanel and, if I've understood something about xaml, this is absolutely correct, that's why I tried forcing the width of the toolbar.
If I use a Grid with a spacing column, the right ToolBarPanel moves correctly to the right, but my control needs to be resized and I guess there's no easy way to assign the correct width to the column.

Is there some easier way to achive my task?

Comment: What do you mean by "my control needs to be resized"? Which control are you talking about?

Comment: As for the grid solution: What is the issue with using a three-column grid with column widths beeing "auto", "*", "auto"?

Comment: The control is inside a Window, so fixed values don't do the job. The grid solution is what I've currently implemented, but it's a pain to add or remove buttons.

Comment: Extending grids can indeed be a chore without a proper editor. The VisualStudios xaml editor does however offer an option to insert/remove grid rows and columns via the context menu that opens when hovering over the left/upper end of the row/column.

Comment: I'm almost new to XAML: are you talking about Visual Studio Blend? Till now I've coded everything writing code down.

Comment: No, I am talking about the standard [Visual Studios XAML editor](https://learn.microsoft.com/de-de/visualstudio/xaml-tools/xaml-code-editor?view=vs-2022) whitch has two parts. One with the code and the other one showing a preview of your element and offering some options to visually edit. While most of these visual eddits will pollute your code, some are quite usefull. One of them is the option to add and remove grid rows/collumns.